# Application Context-Security - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter

Tags: tomcat, servlets, tomcat7, servlet-filters, applicationcontext

I am working on dynamic web project and trying to launch it using tomcat 7 on Spring Tool Suite - Eclipse.

My Server Classpath includes the following jars 
boostrap
tomcat-juli
spring
commons-logging-1.1.1
aspectilib
aspectjrt
aspectjtools
aspectjweaver
spring-ldap-1.3.0.RELEASE-all
spring-security-core-2.0.4

Getting following error when i launch the application

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter

Comment: That's really curious...  In Tomcat 7, servlet-api.jar (which has javax.servlet.Filter) should be in the main Tomcat lib directory...

Comment: I assume so and i didn't add the jar to my classpath manually considering it is already available in tomcat

Comment: I know this might sound like I'm asking you to verify if the world is round, if heat is hot, etc...but it might be worth it to do a "jar -tf servlet-api.jar" to see if the Filter class is really in there.  The Filter class was added in v2.3 of the servlet API.  I just wonder if someone backleveled your jar from v3.0 back to an old version or something crazy like that.

Comment: :) Have filter class as part of the jar. Just verified

Comment: any suggestions anyone?